# Add a "/" between each word in a String

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've got this string :

```
var str:String = mySharedObject.data.theDate;
```

where `mySharedObject.data.theDate` has some words (not always the same words has it depends on which button the user clicked).

So `mySharedObject.data.theDate = "words words words".`

Is it possible to add a "/" between each word ? (without knowing which words are in `mySharedObject.data.theDate`).

In order to have:

`mySharedObject.data.theDate = "words/words/words".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : You can replace " " with "/" in your string, this will split string with " " separator and then join with "/"

```
mySharedObject.data.theDate= mySharedObject.data.theDate.split(" ").join("/")
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: Thx. It worked but just one thing. It does "/words/words/words". Is there anyway to delete the first "/" (before the first "words") ?

Comment: have you a " "  at beginning of your string " words words words" ?

Comment: You can use `trim()` to clear whitespace at the start/end of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that using [`String.replace()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace()) with a little regular expression which will replace all spaces (notice here the `g` (global) flag to replace all instances), like this :

```
var s:String = 'word word word';

trace(s.replace(/\s/g, '/'));       // gives : word/word/word
```

And for more about [regular expressions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdb.html) take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdb.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: A down vote ! Thank you, but could you explain what's the problem of my post and why it's not useful.